# D3 data join fails to add all elements

Tags: d3.js

So I have a standardized array of objects.

```
termometerData = [Object { word="syria",  series=[10] }, Object { word="temporarily",  series=[10] }, ... ]
```

I join them.

```
this.dataPoint = this.chart.selectAll('text')
    .data(function() { return termometerData; })
    .enter().append('text')
    .text(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.word; });
```

The `console.log(d)` only shows me half of the elements from the original array.
Calling `console.log(this.dataPoint)` shows me that the join worked for that half of the elements that were picked up by `console.log(d)` but the other half are null.

The elements that are null are the first 9 elements of the array.

Why did the join fail for the other half of the elements. I have checked the original array and it appears to be totally standardized?

Comment: Did you try `.data(termometerData)`?

Comment: good thought! That was left over from doing some nested joins, but it didn't affect the problem.

Comment: I think you will have a higher chance of getting help if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces your problem.

Comment: It is possible that there were already 9 `text` elements when you made your selection.  After binding your data with `.data(termometerData)` your `.enter()` selection would be everything past the 9th element, unless you use a [key function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/)

Comment: Mmm, right before the posted code this.dataPoint is initialized as an empty array. I can try a key function just to see what happens, should be easy because each element is representing a unique word anyways.

Comment: Adding a key function fixed the problem!!! Thanks all